# Is there a grep and cut command equivalent in Ansible without using command module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I am using below shell command and result is an array of strings'

```
MQSFILEPARSED=$(cat $FILE | grep ' Name=' | cut -d '=' -f2);
```

Is there a way to perform this operation in Ansible without using the command module

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is. For example

```
  vars:
    FILE: test.txt
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        MQSFILEPARSED: "{{ lookup('file', FILE).splitlines()|
                           select('match', '^(.*) Name=(.*)$')|
                           map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                           list }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^(.*)=(.*)$'
        my_replace: '\2'
    - debug:
        var: MQSFILEPARSED
```

gives

```
    "MQSFILEPARSED": [
        "Value", 
        "Value2"
    ]
```

---

Test file

```
$ cat test.txt
line1
line2
 Name=Value
line4
line5 Name=Value2
```

Test script

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
FILE=test.txt
MQSFILEPARSED=$(cat $FILE | grep ' Name=' | cut -d '=' -f2)
printf "$MQSFILEPARSED \n"
```

gives

```
Value
Value2
```